# Date format (MM/dd/yyyy ) in ajax calendar extender

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am building an asp.net application. In that i have 2 date fields, from date and to date. I used the ajax calender extender to show the calender. i need the date in MM/dd/YYYY format and i got it. But the thing is,if I select 12 dec 2013 it appears as 12/12/2013 and if I select 1 dec 2012, then it shows 12/1/2013. So what my issue is i just want the month and date to be in 2 digits always.ie 1 dec 2012 is 12/01/2012.My code is as follows.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_from" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" runat="server" 
        AutoPostBack="True" ontextchanged="txt_from_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txt_from_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txt_from">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: _"f I select 1 dec 2012, then it shows 12/1/2013"_ are you sure about the year?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have missed **Format** attribute in CalendarExtender

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_from" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" runat="server" 
        AutoPostBack="True" ontextchanged="txt_from_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txt_from_CalendarExtender" runat="server"  Format="MM/dd/yyyy"
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txt_from">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 6):

You should use your web.config file as follows

```
<globalization culture="en-GB"/>
```

I think the problem could be the culture problem. If you set it in your web.config file it should 
work.

Here is a msdn link about [culture setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Format property of Calendar Control as like below...

```
Format="MM/dd/yyyy"
```

Answer (score 1):

Globalization is important but not enough. You must add below line into ScriptManager tag.

```
EnableScriptLocalization="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
```

[image][image]